# Linux sed regular expression

Tags: linux, sed, python-re

I have a string:

```
2021-05-27 10:40:50.678117 PID529270:TID 47545543550720:SID 1673488:TXID 786092740:QID 140: INFO:MEMCONTEXT:MemContext state: mem[cur/hi/max] = 9135 / 96586 / 96576 MB, VM[cur/hi/max] = 9161 / 21841178 / 100663296 MB
```

I want to get the number 9135 that first occurrence between '=' and '/', right now, my command as below, it works, but I don't think it's perfect:

```
sed -r 's/.* = ([0-9]+) .* = .*/\1 /'
```

Need a more neat one, please help advise.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sh
sed -En 's~.*= ([0-9]+) /.*=.*~\1~p'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/bj6WA4).

An `awk` solution:

```sh
awk -F= '{gsub(/\/.*|[^0-9]/,"",$2);print $2}'
```

See [this demo](https://ideone.com/GguFTU).

*Details*:

- `-En` - `E` (or `r` as in your example) enables the POSIX ERE syntax and `n` suppresses the default line output
- `.*= ([0-9]+) /.*=.*` - matches any text, `=` + space, captures one or more digits into Grou 1, then matches a space, `/`, then any text, `=` and again any text
- `\1` - replaces with Group 1 value
- `p` - prints the result of the substitution.

Here, `~` are used as regex delimiters in order not to escape `/` in the pattern.

*awk*:

- `-F=` - sets the input field separator to `=`
- `gsub(/\/.*|[^0-9]/,"",$2)` - removes any non-digit or `/` and the rest of the string
- `print $2` - prints the modified Field 2 value.

Answer (score 1):

You could also get the first match with grep using `-P` for Perl-compatible regular expressions.

```
grep -oP "^.*? = \K\d+(?= /)"
```

- `^` Start of string
- `.*?` Match as least as possible chars
- `=`  Match space `=` and space
- `\K\d+` Forget what is matched so far
- `(?= /)` Assert a space and `/` to the right

Output

```
9135
```

See a [bash demo](https://tio.run/##ZY7dSsNAEIVfZciVVdPMbnZmNktKoT9CkG0rBim0ClGX1otYaSP07eOWXnp1zsx8czjvzWnf97tj@IH0sILkbXg7hhFsH7efdzfjEWSDBMqyhESjVilSqgUUOoOOcMhilRJYVTPShRZ0dTUDI2SITE6EotE9x5ViyY21rl7HQSxjhGPC0@UUFarFw9L5uZ8uF/V8XTsf2unhuwvnDk5d0wUHbWg3H7/HbP@Vtc35NTYsVE6QQcFk@arC4Cf38OL/kawioZU1sa2NViEy57q4PCR9/wc)

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the material between the first `=` and the first `/`, ignoring the spaces, you could use:

```
sed -E -e 's%^[^=]*= ([^/]*) /.*$%\1%'
```

This uses Extended Regular Expressions (ERE) (`-E`; `-r` also works with GNU `sed`), and searches from the start of the line for a sequence of 'not `=`' characters, the `=` character, a space, anything that's not a slash (which is remembered), another space, a slash, and anything that follows, replacing it all with what was remembered.  The `^` and `$` anchors aren't crucial; it will work the same without them.  The `%` symbols are used instead of `/` because the searched-for pattern includes a `/`.  If your sure there'll never be any spaces other than the first and last ones between the `=` and `/`, you can use `[^ /]*` in place of `[^/]*` and there should be some small (probably immeasurable) performance benefit.